# Android: Find API calls requiring permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, lint

I'm making changes to existing code to make it compliant with the new permissions model in Android M. The app declares the READ_PHONE_STATE permission in its manifest which will require me to prompt the user to grant it at runtime. How can I locate all API calls which require this permission so I can prompt the user? I tried commenting out the permission from the manifest but the app built without errors in Android Studio 1.5.1. I also ran the lint tool while making sure that permission checking is turned on as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795454/analyze-code-with-lint-for-calls-that-require-permissions) but found no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, just found the following threads, hopefully still can help.
[How to find required Android Marshmallow runtime permissions in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679400/how-to-find-required-android-marshmallow-runtime-permissions-in-code) and [How to find out which permission an android application needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786850/how-to-find-out-which-permission-an-android-application-needs)